# Windows 7 OK button on Copy To dialog doesn't copy profile

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, user-profiles, event-log, windows-embedded-7

So I am attempting to copy a User Profile to the default profile. I am using WinSpy++ to enable the disabled "Copy To" button - this process works on a stock laptop I have here.

However, this does not work in a customised image I have with a fair amount of registry settings changed and policies applied. Additionally, I should be able to copy the default profile over another profile regardless, but I cannot.

The Application Event log lists this:

```
Error Instrument: ProcessName: systempropertiesadvanced.exe 
WindowTitle: Copy To  MsgCaption: Confirm Copy  MsgText:
C:\Users\username\Desktop\test already exists. The current contents of this
directory or this file will be deleted during this operation.  Are you
sure you want to continue? 
CallerModuleName: unknown  
BaseAddr: 0XFFFFFFFF        ImageSize: 0XFFFFFFFF         ReturnAddr: 0X00000001
```

It is the contents of the popup that should show up when I click OK on the copy to dialog... before the profile copy is actually performed.

I intend to diff the registry settings between a known working system and this system... but it is a lot to wade through.

Additionally... The image it does not work on is a Windows Standard Embedded 7 install and after testing it doesn't work even with a mostly clean install so it could be something missing from the installation. I also noticed there are other pop up type messages not displaying (I noticed them in the event logs)

The Event ID is 1072

Answer (score 1):

EnableDefaultReply for MessageBoxes was set in the registry.

Details here (Just search for EnableDefaultReply if the link goes dead): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940850(v=WinEmbedded.5).aspx

> 1. In the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control registry key, create a new key named Error Message Instrument.
> 2. Under the Error Message Instrument key, add the values of type REG_DWORD from the following table.
>
> EnableDefaultReply 0x00000001 Enables the Enable Default Reply
>   feature.

This cuases windows to auto reply to messageboxes... and meaning it was auto canceling my profile copy.

Comment: To accomplish this from a command line you can use this:

    reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Error Message Instrument" /v EnableDefaultReply /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Comment: Sure but anyone that should be mucking about the registry would already know that...